# Is there a way to delete/get rid of a Man-In-the-Browser infection?

Tags: infection

I was cruising around the browser reading articles about MItB and still can't find a technical way of getting rid of an MItB infection. hence, I was wondering: Is there is such a way to delete an MItB attack technically? If you were to click an infected link on a computer or mobile through a browser, in which triggered the MItB and infects your web browser, can you destroy the vulnerability by reinstalling the browser, whether in your phone or computer? More importantly, does MItB make any difference in computer and phones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man in the browser (mitb) is a nasty attack because "traditional" security mechanisms are not very effective against it. This is a classic example of a Trojan because the "enemy" is behind your city wall (security layers). Encryption won't help because the data the attacker is accessing is already decrypted. So the attacker has the chance to inject scripts, modify transactions, collect personal data, etc., without the user's knowledge. From the user's POV, everything is fine. They won't notice anything is wrong until the damage is done.

Your idea of reinstalling the browser is unlikely to work. The Trojan can survive the reinstall because it is not part of the browser itself. It is either an extension (or "browser helper object"), malicious JavaScript, or an external program which messes with the browser's API calls.

Also, active detection and mitigation by antivirus and other anti-malware software is not very successful. AV will detect some Trojans, but the detection rates are low. Trojans are, by design, engineered to avoid detection.

One approach you will often hear mentioned is 2-factor authentication or out-of-band transaction verification. The most common is to send a code to the user's phone or e-mail. In some systems, this code will also include information about the specific transaction which is being verified. The idea here is that the phone or other communication channel will not be impacted by the Trojan, so it should be safe from interference. But honestly I don't really think this is 100% safe. You will still have users who ignore any warning signs in the message and just blindly continue typing in the verification code into their browser because they are 1) ignorant 2) in a hurry, or both. And even then, you are assuming the the out-of-band communication mechanism has not been compromised. That's a big assumption. If you're wrong, then it will be completely ineffective.

Another approach is to sidestep the problem and look at the user's behavior from the server side. If you can establish a model of their "normal" behavior, then there is a reasonable chance of identifying suspicious activity. What is suspicious activity? It can be anything like a sudden increase in large transactions, changing IP address in the middle of a session, and navigating between pages in an "unnatural" way. When this type of behavior is detected, you can notify the user or take steps like locking their account or just rejecting a transaction. Of course, this will be limited to a specific service (e.g. the user's bank) and there is always a chance of false positives. It doesn't address the root of the problem, because the user's platform will still be infected.

The defense right now is not detection but prevention. Stop the Trojan from getting in. The most obvious one. Don't download and open or execute anything unless you trust the source 100%. That means the source should have E2E encryption and a trustworthy SSL (TLS) cert, preferably extended validation (EV).

Also make sure your OS is up to date with the latest security patches. Finally, don't use browsers with known vulnerabilities. And even then, avoid suspicious browser plugins/extensions.